# Handling remote: true links and searchbots

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, bots, ujs, google-crawlers

I use `remote: true` links a lot. In most cases, the response can be `js` or `html`, so searchbots don't cause a problem

But some links, are purely js response, and there is no HTML response (which causes exceptions and errors, which flood monitoring tools, email, alerts, etc)

How can I setup the link so searchbots (google,bing, other crawlers) won't try it?

Or - Is there a type of response I should return so the crawlers will know not to go back to that url?

Answer (score 1):

`rel="nofollow"` is what you can put on your links. that should prevent bots like google form crawling them https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en